# Java Hazelcast problems with multiple clusters

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I am running a small system that relies on Hazelcast for clustering, distributed computing and messaging in a Multicast mode (Standard config as available in the download). I have a number of server modules that run as "Core" Hazelcast instances and a Java Swing application that is implemented as a Hazelcast "Native Client". This all works well and I would now like to commission the system in production and would hence need to run two separate clusters (dev + prod) and that is where I run into problems.

According to the [documentation](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#ConfigGroup)  all you need to is to use separate group names + passwords for the two clusters and I get the impression that the two clusters should sort themselves out automatically!? This appears to work for the server modules but when I try to connect a "Client"-instance to the prod environment, I can see from the logs of one of the server modules in prod that the client appears to connect successfully:

```
INFO: [prod] received auth from Connection [/192.168.0.2:55863 -> null] live=true,
client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, this group name:prod, auth group name:prod, 
successfully authenticated
```

But, the client never shows up as a member of prod. Instead, I find that the client has become a member of the dev environment even though the authentification took place against prod!

Involontary mixing of the two clusters is obviously a giant problem for me and a showstopper. Does anyone know if there is anything that I am doing wrong or if there are any configuration changes that I can do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a client connects to the cluster it never becomes a member of the cluster.

So I suspect that your client did connected to the prod, but somehow in your code you have somewhere something like Hazelcat.getMap() which results in starting a member in that JVM and since the default configuration that this member will use will be same as the dev, this new member will join to your dev cluster.

So in fact you have one client, that is connected to prod and another member that is connected to the dev cluster.

Try to put something through client and see in which cluster those entries are appear?

Am i making sense?

Comment: Absolutely. Makes sense. I am a little short on time now but I will test your suggestions early next week and revert back. Thank you so much for the quick answer Fuad.

Comment: You were correct. I had code in my clients that started members using the default config "dev". I ended up switching my clients to Super Clients as that appeared to be an easier fix for me. My core modules (members) needs to be aware of connected clients and the Native Clients "appeared less visible" to the members. Either way, the Super Client implementation serves my purposes fine. Thank you so much for your help.